# Creating a Prolog predicate via macro-like meta programming

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming, swi-prolog

I need a way for this to work:

```
?- create_pred(f, [A, B], (write(That), write(B), write(A), write(This))).
true.
?- f(this, a, b).
_L154bathis
true.
```

I have it working without the `This` so far:

```
?- create_pred(f, [A, B], (write(That), write(B), write(A))).
true.
?- f(a, b).
_L154ba
true.
```

The code for that is the following:

```
create_pred(Name, Args, Body) :-
    length(Args, Argc),
    functor(F, Name, Argc),
    term_variables(F, Vars),
    term_variables(Args, Vars),
    assertz((F :- Body)).
```

Any idea how I could get that first argument unified with the `This` (and not the `That`) variable from the body?

Comment: Can't you just call `create_pred(f, [This, A, B], (write(That), write(B), write(A), write(This))).` then try `f(this, a, b)`?

Comment: @lurker I think you mean `write(This)` instead of `write(That)` but otherwise, yeah, completely.

Comment: @lurker That would work, Yes, but unfortunately not, no. I cannot change the "interface" so to speak. (Using atoms as argument list and body would solve the issue, too, but is also not possible)

Comment: @DanielLyons I just copied the OP's `create_pred` call and it gave the result the OP said was desired.

Comment: @DanielJour yes but no? You'll need to edit your question and explain your constraints. It's not clear what you're allowed to do.